# Is there any difference between like '%A%' statement and in('A') statement when this field is exactly equal to 'A'?

Tags: sql, hiveql

I think if this field has more than one character, then `in ('something')` is faster than `like '%something%'`, right?

But what if there is only one character?

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'name',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='example';
```

```
INSERT INTO `example` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C'),
    (4, 'D'),
    (5, NULL),
    (6, 'E');
```

So, what's the difference between `select * from example where name like '%A%';` and `select * from example where name in ('A');`?  Is `in` faster than `like`？

Furthermore, what about `select * from example where name like '%%';` and `select * from example where name in ('A','B','C','D','E');`

Comment: For one, the `LIKE` version won't be able to use an index, if one exists.

Comment: `like '%%'` used to find part of content (of course you can find entire value with this method). `IN` used to find exact value in the provided list. If your data is `xxxAxxx`, `yyyByyy`, ... you will see the different.

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, these expressions can use an index:

```
where name = 'A'
where name in ('A')
where name like 'A%'
```

And this cannot use a standard index:

```
where name like '%A%'
```

The reason is because there is a wildcard at the beginning of the pattern.

In general, you are not relying on indexes for performance in Hive.  You may have similar issues if your data is partitioned by `name` -- in which case I doubt that `LIKE` would ever prune the partitions.

So, I think the difference in performance is the overhead of `LIKE` to a string comparison.  I would imagine that `LIKE` would be a little more expensive, but not wildly more expensive.

Feel free to run timings to see how it performs on your system, though.